# MySQL Configuration

Tags: mysql

where am I going to set the parameter values for the following in my.cnf?:

```
read_buffer_size
sort_buffer_size
net_buffer_length
```

is it under MyISAM of Mysqld?

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got It!!!! all of them should be set under [mysqld]